# Convert nested `Vec`s to nested slices in a function

Tags: rust, reference, slice, lifetime

I'm trying to get a nested slices from a nested `Vec` by calling a function. The idea works for plain non-nested vectors so I guess it should also work for nested `Vec`s.

I could understand the `error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value` issue from `f2` (since I recreated a new `Vec`) and basic lifetime stuff.

I need a way to fix it but I can't figure out how (to reuse the `Vec` passed in instead of creating a new one as temporary value). Also my original way seems a bit clunky.

If that's not impossible, why?

Thanks!

```
fn f1(v: &Vec<u8>) -> &str {
    std::str::from_utf8(v).unwrap()
}

fn f2(v: &Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> &[&str] {
    &v.iter()
        .map(|x| std::str::from_utf8(&x).unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()[..]
}

fn main() {
    let v1: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    f1(&v1);

    let v2: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![vec![1, 2, 3]];
    f2(&v2);
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to use the return value for and how? `&[&str]` isn't a good option for this as you're seeing, but there are plenty of alternatives if you elaborate on your usage.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Hi, I'm just trying to make `fn f2(v: &Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> &[&str]` work and understand why if it's impossible. I store some data into a struct like this, and just want to reference them.

Comment: It is impossible. But it seems like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's not. I know little about the underlying mechanism about Rust. And just wonder why it is possible for 1D but impossible for 2D data. My simple mind is: whatever reference in, just send them to return values (the function doesn't own it)...

Comment: Do you understand the error message and what it means? It looks like you got used to garbage-collected language.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, as I said in the description, I know I create a temporary value value in `f2` which causes the error. So I'm looking for a way to not to create it just like that in `f1`. But I'm not sure if it's possible due to my current limit knowledge.

Comment: It is not possible, as pointed out by @Scherzo. They have different memory layout.

Answer (score 2):

Doing so requires making new stuff, which is a Vector of &str pointers - the pointers used for &Vec are different than &str - at that time [mem::transmute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) is called. So I am afraid you cannot make this in the given context - you would have to create more data, and it will be destroyed after leaving the function - which makes returning a reference to it a bad idea.